# Pass additional parameter to Python pipe (pipetools)

Tags: python, parameters, pipe

Is it possible to pass additional parameter to pipe, for example:

We have:

```
v= (s > pipe | a | b | c)
```

this is the same as

```
v= c(b(a(s)))
```

How is it possible to use pipe with something like:

```
v= c(b(a(s), d))
```

Comment: Why not just use `v= c(b(a(s), d))`? What does `pipe` give you?

Comment: [Pipetools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipetools) attempt to simplify function composition and make it more readable  - it's a good reason to write clear and readable code.

Comment: Well: 1. that's *less* readable to the overwhelming majority of Python users; and 2. did you actually *read* that documentation, which gives examples of using `partial`s to achieve this?

Comment: `odd_sum = pipe | xrange | partial(ifilter, lambda x: x % 2) | sum`  Sorry I'm new in Python, but as I can see `partial` doesn't accept parameter from pipe, `ifilter` accepts incoming parameter and `partial` uses only 2 arguments: what `ifilter` returns and `lambda x: x % 2`, or am I wrong?


I tried constructions like
`v= (s > pipe | a | b(d) | c)`
and
`v= (s > pipe | a | b(s, d) | c)`
doesn't work

Comment: Reread the partial and pipe documentation. What does *"doesn't accept parameter from pipe"* mean, it's just for creating general callables with some parameters preset. It's not clear why you ever thought those *"constructions"* would work.

Comment: 1. Doesn't work because function b accept 2 parameters
2. Formally 2nd case works but it doesn't pass to b result of a(s), just passing init s value. 

I need to pass to b(var1, var2) one argument from pipe (which is the result of a(s)) and another variable from general scope

Comment: Please give a [mcve] of the code you're trying to write and the problems with it. It is certainly possible to write a `partial` that allows `b` to be called with a single argument from the pipe and another argument set from scope, it's not clear from your comments why you're failing to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

Library author here, randomly found this question now, but maybe it will still help someone.

If you need partial application where the pipe input has to go in front of, or in the middle, of the partially applied arguments, you can mark the space for it with the `X` object. So for your example, you would do:

```
from pipetools import pipe, X

...

v = s > pipe | a | (b, X, d) | c
```

This is enabled by the `xpartial` function and can also be used outside of a pipe. More information [in the docs](https://0101.github.io/pipetools/doc/xpartial.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to the example here http://0101.github.io/pipetools/doc/#automatic-partial-application-in-the-pipe

you can use `v= s > pipe | a | (b,d) | c`

which equals to `v= c(b(d, a(s)))`

I do not know how to get `v= c(b(a(s), d))` or if that is supported by the pipetools package

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon only this answer, and in case someone needs another use case,

```
>>> from pipetools import pipe,X

>>> def multArgs(x,y):
       return x+y+1

>>> 1 > pipe | (multArgs,2) #4
```